# PIL installation on MAC

Tags: installation, python-imaging-library

I am trying to install PIL in my Mac.I am using the following command:

```
sudo pip install pil --allow-external pil --allow-unverified pil
```

But it gives the following error

```
Command "/Users/akira/anaconda/bin/python -c "import setuptools,     tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-bCxMjA/pil/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-YwCGxg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-bCxMjA/pil
```

Please note that,I have condo installed in my system.I am not able to install PIL in my system in any means.Please help me with this.I have browsed many links,But no solution works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `pip` if you have `conda` installed? I installed it simply with the command:

```
conda install pil
```

Or if you want the latest version (since PIL is now called pillow):

```
conda install pillow
```

Comment: @akira, Please accept sufficient answers with the checkmark button.  It's worth +2 rep to you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when i upgrade my pip,here is what i did(Mac OS  10.11, python ver 2.7.11).

1.Download PIl : http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/
(ver1.1.6 more compatible with python 2.7,ver1.1.7 have many problems)

2.Run this code in your terminal(cd to your download directory)

```
$ tar xvfz Imaging-1.1.6.tar.gz
$ cd Imaging-1.1.6
$ python setup.py install
```

3.Use 'pip list' to check your PIL.and if your install pillow,you can only use one of them.so if you want to use PIL only , uninstall pillow by

```
sudo -s    
pip uninstall pillow
```